# Zsh command substitution

Tags: cron, zsh

I usually work with BASH, but I'm trying to setup a cronjob from a machine and user account that is configured with zsh.  When the cronjob runs, the date variable does not contain the date, just the string for the command to return the date.

```
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
55 15 *  *  1-5  scp user@host:/path/to/some/file/$DATE.log /tmp
```

I've tried using backticks rather than $() around the command, but that did not work either.  Is there a special way to do command substitution in zsh?

Comment: If you add a line to the crontab similar to this: `* * * * * env > /tmp/cron.env` you'll probably find `SHELL=/bin/sh` in that file regardless of whether the user's shell is set to Bash or zsh. But that's not why your variable isn't getting set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a line from the user's crontab, then the line to set the variable isn't set by the shell, it's set by cron itself - and as you've discovered, it doesn't do a lot of interpretation on the values!

The values *do* get set, but set literal values in the process's environment - and environment variables don't get interpreted further after being expanded - so the `$(date)` stays as `$(date)`, as you've seen.

The easiest thing to do would be:

```
55 15 * * 1-5 scp user@host:/path/to/file/`date +%Y%m%d`.log /tmp
```

The backticks `` are another way to interpolate the result of a command, that works in more shells than `$(command)` (though it is less flexible, since you can't nest it).

Comment: You can nest `` but it gets messy fast if you have to nest more than one level.

Comment: You can in some shells, but not in others; I'm not sure of the details so I try to avoid ever nesting it :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the `cron` way of setting up environment variables supports the `$()` stuff. It doesn't even support variable substitutions.

I think you'll either have to put the date calculation into the `cron` command:

```
55 15 *  *  1-5  scp user@host:/path/to/some/file/$(date +%Y%m%d).log /tmp
```

or create another script which sets the variable then calls `scp` with it (and of course you call *that* script from within your `crontab`).